# Need a tool to edit dates on image and video files

Tags: windows, exif, metadata-editor

I need a tool that reads all date values from an image or video file and sets them all the same value, by taking the **oldest date**. For example for [this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egqXE.png) I'd like to have all these values set to 04/03/2023. I'd like to that in bulk for a large number of files.

I saw some tools online, but they only take into consideration creation date, modified date and accessed date. I need something that also considers [these values for images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKRRV.png) and [this for videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY5Q9.png).

Comment: The keyword you need for those (at least for the images) is "Exif"; those are data stored within the header of the corresponding files. On Linux there are things like `exiftool` and `jhead` for bulk-processing at the command-line. No idea for Windows, though (I threw my last copy through its name before it became 95, using purely Linux for more than 20 years now).

Comment: You can use ExifTool on Windows as well, within e.g. PowerShell script. However, your question is kind of unanswerable in a more detailed way due to inaccurate requirement(s). E.g. do you want the date fields to be automatically detected or do you have a predefined list? Should system ones like "last modified date" on Windows count? Etc. You need to specify more details.